# $A=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}+\dots+\frac{1}{19}+\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{31}+\dots+\frac{1}{91}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{101}+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, summation, harmonic-numbers

Consider the series:

$$A=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{12}+\dots+\frac{1}{19}+\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{31}+\frac{1}{41}+\dots+\frac{1}{91}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{101}+\frac{1}{102}+\dots$$

The numerator of each term is $1$, and the denominators are the natural numbers that contain the digit $1$.

If the denominators, instead, are the natural numbers omitting numbers containing the digit $9$ is called Kempner series, it converges to $22.92067661926415034816...$.

> What is the value of $A$?
>
> Does $A$ have an exact form?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$A\gt\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{10k+1}\gt\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{11k}=\infty $$
Hence the sum determining $A$ does not converge and $A$ does not exist.

Comment: Except for the first term of $A$, the $n$th term of $A$ is less than the $n$th term of Kempner series. Since Kempner series converges, then $A$ must converges too. Am I right?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari:  No.  The Kempner series omits all terms where the number contains a $9$, which is almost all of them.  A number with lots of digits is almost certain to contain a $9$.  Your series contains almost all the terms of the harmonic series, which diverges.

Comment: Just because the $n$th term is less than another sequence, having infinitely many more terms can still cause divergence. Like in this case where practically every number in the harmonic series is included as the number of terms increases.

Comment: @RossMillikan So here another question to be raised; The $n$th term in $A>$ the $n$th term in Kempner series, what is the value of $n$?

Comment: I would start on that by considering how many terms are in each series in a decade.  Kempner has $8$ one digit denominators, $72$ two digit, $648$ three digit and so on.  $A$ has one one digit denominator, $18$ two digit and so on.  It will take getting into a number of digits before $A$ overtakes Kempner, but it will, probably in six or seven digits.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari There are $8\cdot 9^{n-1}$ n digits Kempner numbers. There are at least $10^{n-1}$ n digit numbers in your series (all those starting with 1). Note that $$\sum_{k=1}^{23} 8\cdot 9^{k-1}=9^{23}-1<10^{23-1}$$ But since the $10^{n-1}$ is very rough underestimate, the flip happens earlier.